# neo4j - The size of the database is 28 MB despite no data is stored

Tags: neo4j

As the title of the question clearly describes, the size of my database is **28.16 MB** despite I have **removed all the data stored**. I have added the detail of the database below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a knowledge base article on [understanding database growth](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-database-growth/) which covers this in detail.

The summary here is that when data is deleted, we mark the records in the store as deleted, so they continue to exist and take up space, but after meeting some conditions they will be eligible for reuse when new data is added later.

In addition we keep track of the ids of deleted and eligible-for-reuse spaces in the store files which will grow during deletes, but shrink during later ingestion (as the ids are reused and removed from the .id files), so you may see a counterintuitive effect: growing of the db size during deletions (since we're adding the ids to the .id files) and shrinking during additions when filling in those reusable places in the store files (as the ids are used up and removed from the .id files).

Lastly, we also have [transaction logs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/transaction-logs/), which will be holding transactional history for the database and can often be quite large, and the rotation and retention properties in your neo4j.conf will determine how often these get flushed to the store files, and how/when they are pruned. Never move or delete these files yourself, change the rotation and/or retention properties in the conf file to manage these.

If wanting to start from scratch, the cleanest way is to shut down Neo4j and delete the graph.db folder, and it will be recreated on the next startup.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It seems there are no commands for that which would make it easier and also safer I think.